# white undefined?

Tags: color, pdf

I'm trying to change my compilation chain from lualatex + dvips + ps2pdf to lualatex in pdf mode. Some things that used to work don't anymore.

For example, this code :

```
%-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\white Text

\end{document}
```

produces the error :

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7300 64-bit)
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./white_bug.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
 L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/svgnam.def"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def")
(./white_bug.aux) ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.11 \white
          Text
```

Distribution : MikTeX 2.9

command line : `lualatex --output-format=pdf "white_bug.tex"`

changing white to White doesn't work either...

Comment: show a log file of a compilation where this worked with an engine. btw: unless you changed something lualatex creates pdf so setting an output format is quite unneeded.

Comment: Use `\color{white}`, instead of `\white`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't compile this example with --output-format=dvi either. I'll edit the question to not induce errors. Concerning --output-device=pdf, weirdly enough, if I don't mention it, I can't compile file using texgraph package with tikz output option.

Comment: Indeed, \color{white} works. But I can state that \white alone worked in my previous works (not this ECM), so there must be a package that defines \white. I'll investigate...

Comment: Just to clarify : ```\white``` (along with other colors commands) is defined by pstricks, not by tikz.